# Textview disappers but listview is visible

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, textview

I tried to put textview at top of listview in layout, but the content of textview is not visible. In the design view there is space of the relative layout but I don't see the content.

Here is my layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id = "@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:padding = "5dp"
        android:text = "@string/product"
        android:textColor = "#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "2"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:padding = "5dp"
        android:text = "@string/category"
        android:textColor = "#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "1.5"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:padding = "5dp"
        android:text = "@string/quantity"
        android:textColor = "#ffffff" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:padding = "5dp"
        android:text = "@string/price"
        android:textColor = "#ffffff" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
<ListView
    android:id = "@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight = "1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please guide.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpN1a.png)

Comment: using fill_parent as listview height is making it cover the whole screen hiding your relativelayout with textview below it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Product"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Category"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Quantity"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Change Your layout with this will solve your problem.One More thing when you want to manage your layout with weight then always use LinearLayout because the weight concept is not supported by RelativeLayout.

Comment: Thank your Rishabh now my content is shown. But I am having hard time to align the content inside the textview can you help it with.

Comment: I am not getting you, Can you please ellaborate.

Comment: Like the first column is product, but my product is shown like pro on single line and duct in another line

Comment: Show me your screen shot

Comment: Yes I did that.

Comment: And replace the complete code with this,cause i think you are using Linear layout width to wrap content.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id = "@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:padding = "5dp"
        android:text = "@string/product"
        android:textColor = "#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "2"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:padding = "5dp"
        android:text = "@string/category"
        android:textColor = "#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "1.5"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:padding = "5dp"
        android:text = "@string/quantity"
        android:textColor = "#ffffff" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:padding = "5dp"
        android:text = "@string/price"
        android:textColor = "#ffffff" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
<ListView
    android:id = "@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight = "1"
    android:marginTop="16dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```